# swap between rows in a 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a java code that should swap between two 2d rows and I have completed it but I want to check if my work is correct and if it needs any modification to do.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    
    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void exchangeAnyTwoRows(int[][] matrix,
                                          int K, int L)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
            
            int temp = matrix[K - 1][i];
            matrix[K - 1][i] = matrix[L - 1][i];
            matrix[L - 1][i] = temp;
        }
        
        printMatrix(matrix);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int K = 2, L = 3;
        int mat[][] = { { 2, 1, 4 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 3, 6, 2 } };
  
        exchangeAnyTwoRows(mat, K, L);
    }
}
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are swapping each element in the two rows. I don't think you need to do it in that way. You can just swap the rows at once:

```
  public static void exchangeAnyTwoRows(int[][] matrix, int r1, int r2) {
    int[] temp = matrix[r1];
    matrix[r1] = matrix[r2];
    matrix[r2] = temp;
  }
```

One other comment is that the above code will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The reason is that your row index starts from 1. You may decrease each index inside the method, however, just use 0 based indexes would be better to avoid confusion.

So, you may want to modify the values of `K` and `L` to `1` and `2`, respectively.

Comment: I did not get your point can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @adnanadel which additional clarifications would be helpful for you?